# Transfer sound to remote computer

Tags: remote-desktop, audio, remote, audio-streaming

I have been looking for a while, for solution to a certain problem, with limited success.

What I wanted to do is to transfer sound **TO** remote computer, not **from** remote computer.

I'm looking for a **seamless solution** that works, to play some tracks/video on local computer, and have them streamed to remote (or LAN) computer in real-time. I suppose bandwidth is not a problem, especially on a LAN infrastructure...

Already tried various remote desktop solutions (all transfer from, not to remote PC), VLC player...

To summarize: Transferring sound (stereo mix) from local sound card to LAN (Remote) computer on Windows platform. Alternatively, a video/audio player (or a player plugin) with similar capabilities will do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `From` and `To` are really dependent on which you are currently on!

Answer (score 1):

Reverse your client and server :P
Local would be the server
Remote would be the client
You could install it both ways but ultimately it is impossible to client feed a server, although communication is possible both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I think vlc can be used as an on demand audio streamer, not only playback tranfert. but never use it like that. BTW I don't know what you mean by from and to but streaming are made to come from a server to à client. So your client aka remote needs to connect to your server aka local.

Comment: Sorry for being a little fuzzy on the details...
Sound would play on remote "server"... I would play a track/video on my laptop (client) and would like the sound to be played by "server", preferably in sync with local (client) playback. 
Thanks!