# Windows 7 use remote PC as speakers?

Tags: windows-7, audio, remote, speakers

Is it possible to "export" all sounds from one PC to another so it would act as a remote speaker?

I have a media PC connected to my TV and surround system. I'd like to be able to play games, watch movies etc on my laptop, and have all sounds played through my surround system that's connected to my media PC. Both PC's have Windows 7.

Comment: Similar/possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/264351/transfer-sound-to-remote-computer

Answer (score 0):

While you can connect the two PC's and play a movie on your laptop from your desktop, Video Games are a little difficult. mstsc automatically will play sounds from the remote machine on your local machine. So soundwise, you're set, Games however, are a very different story in my experience.

Directions

- Run mstsc
- Type in IP address of local laptop from Desktop
- Enter User Credentials, Play Movie.

NOTE: I havent tried this in a while so depending on your setup, You may have better quality when viewing movies and playing games than I had. Wired connections will be better than wireless.

Good Luck!

Comment: My goal is to have the remote PC act as a sound card or something. I'm wondering if it's possible..

Comment: The short answer is yes. But it will have to remain connected via RDP to the laptop.

Comment: Will try the edit shortly :)

Comment: I've tried to remote desktop from my laptop to my media PC, and enabled the "Play on remote computer" option for sound - didn't work at all. I tried to connect from my media PC to my laptop, but then I can't use my laptop as it logs out for the session, and if I try to login - the session drops :/

Comment: A second solution and one I personally have tried and for sound sake I know works is Chrome Remote Desktop. I guarentee that the sound will transfer and game visuals WILL NOT. Other solution is Chrome RDP. Also after some google-fu I found this: [link](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/119903-13-remote-desktop-gaming)